# How to plot a graph in a labelframe using tkinter and matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a simple GUI using `tkinter` and `matplotlib`. I want to plot inside a `LabelFrame`, but when I try to plot again using a new entries, it overlap the new graph with the old one. How can I plot just the last graph? I'm almost sure the problem it the last lines of code or the way how  I declare the frame. My plan is to have a window with more a graphs, each one in their own frame.

Here's what I have tired :

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def main():

    root = Tk.Tk()
    gui = Window(root)
    gui.root.mainloop()

    return None
class Window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Overpressure Estimation")
        self.root.geometry('1400x500')

        parameters_frame =LabelFrame(self.root, text="Blast parameters", padx=20,pady=20)
        parameters_frame.pack(padx=1,pady=1)
        self.parameters_frame = parameters_frame

        graph_frame =LabelFrame(self.root, text="Graphs", padx=20,pady=20)
        graph_frame.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

        self.graph_frame = graph_frame

        self.charge = 100
        self.distance = 100
        self.kasite = 516
        self.asite = -1.45


        charge = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Charge Q (Kg)")
        self.charge_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.charge_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        charge.grid(row=0, column=0)

        distance = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Distance (m)")
        self.distance_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.distance_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        distance.grid(row=1, column=0)

        kasite = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Site constant (K)")
        self.kasite_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.kasite_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        kasite.grid(row=2, column=0)

        asite = Label(parameters_frame ,  text = "Site exponent (a)")
        self.asite_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.asite_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        asite.grid(row=3, column=0)



        button1 = Button(self.parameters_frame, text = "Calculate",command = self.update_values)
        parameters_frame.bind("<Return>", self.update_values)
        self.plot_values()
        button1.grid(row=5, column=1)
        pass

    def update_values(self, event=None):

        self.charge = int(self.charge_entry.get())
        self.distance = int(self.distance_entry.get())
        self.kasite = int(self.kasite_entry.get())
        self.asite = float(self.asite_entry.get())
        self.plot_values()
        return None

    pass

    def plot_values(self):

        # GRAPH
        z1 = [np.round(10 * np.log10((((((i/(self.charge**(1/3)))**self.asite) * self.kasite)/(0.00002))**2)),0) 
                       for i in np.arange(0.1,self.distance + 1) ]

        line_1 = [120 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        line_2 = [125 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        line_3 = [133 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        x1 = np.arange(1, self.distance + 1) 

        figure1 = plt.figure(figsize = (6,5), dpi = 100)
        figure1.add_subplot(111)

        plt.plot(z1,label="Decay Curve")
        plt.plot(x1, line_3,'b--',label="130 dbL: Maximum for Structural Damage Level" )
        plt.plot(x1, line_2,'r--',label="125 dbL: Maximum for Human Comfort Level" )
        plt.plot(x1, line_1,'g--',label="120 dbL: Annoying" )
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
        plt.ylabel('Sound  Pressure Level(dBL)',labelpad=1)
        plt.title('SPL DECAY')
        plt.xscale('log')
        plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")

        chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1,self.graph_frame)
        chart.get_tk_widget().pack()
   
      
        return None
    pass
main()
```

Comment: Are you trying to, clear and make another graph when clicked in calculate?

Comment: What you should be doing is to re-use the same `canvas` when you plot again. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001195/how-to-update-a-graph-created-by-matplotlib-in-tkinter/59004437#59004437) if you need.

Comment: @Xitiz yes, something like that

Comment: I think that link provided by OP solved almost your problem but I am confused in how to plot that data again. I will post the answer, check that, if it doesn't solved your problem then I may delete it? @StonedBored I am tkinter user I haven't used "FigureCanvasTkAgg" but now I understand basics.

Comment: @StonedBored check my answer, it is working as you expect, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def main():

    root = Tk.Tk()
    gui = Window(root)
    gui.root.mainloop()

    return None
class Window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Overpressure Estimation")
        self.root.geometry('1400x500')

        parameters_frame =LabelFrame(self.root, text="Blast parameters", padx=20,pady=20)
        parameters_frame.pack(padx=1,pady=1)
        self.parameters_frame = parameters_frame

        graph_frame =LabelFrame(self.root, text="Graphs", padx=20,pady=20)
        graph_frame.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

        self.graph_frame = graph_frame

        self.charge = 100
        self.distance = 100
        self.kasite = 516
        self.asite = -1.45

        charge = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Charge Q (Kg)")
        self.charge_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.charge_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.charge_entry.insert(0,7)
        charge.grid(row=0, column=0)

        distance = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Distance (m)")
        self.distance_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.distance_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        distance.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.distance_entry.insert(0,7)
        kasite = Label(self.parameters_frame ,  text = "Site constant (K)")
        self.kasite_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.kasite_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        kasite.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.kasite_entry.insert(0,7)
        asite = Label(parameters_frame ,  text = "Site exponent (a)")
        self.asite_entry = Entry(self.parameters_frame ,  width = 15)
        self.asite_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        asite.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.asite_entry.insert(0,7)

        button1 = Button(self.parameters_frame, text = "Calculate",command = self.update_values)
        parameters_frame.bind("<Return>", self.update_values)
 
        button1.grid(row=5, column=1)
        
        self.test()
        frame=Frame(self.graph_frame)
        frame.pack()
        self.frame=frame
        chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure1,self.frame)
        chart.get_tk_widget().pack()
    
        self.chart =chart

    def update_values(self, event=None):

        self.charge = int(self.charge_entry.get())
        self.distance = int(self.distance_entry.get())
        self.kasite = int(self.kasite_entry.get())
        self.asite = float(self.asite_entry.get())
        self.plot_values()
        return None
    
    def test(self):
        z1 = [np.round(10 * np.log10((((((i/(self.charge**(1/3)))**self.asite) * self.kasite)/(0.00002))**2)),0) for i in np.arange(0.1,self.distance + 1) ]
        line_1 = [120 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        line_2 = [125 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        line_3 = [133 for i in range(1,self.distance + 1)]
        x1 = np.arange(1, self.distance + 1) 
        figure1 = plt.figure(figsize = (6,5), dpi = 100)
        figure1.add_subplot(111)
        
        self.figure1=figure1
        plt.plot(z1,label="Decay Curve")
        plt.plot(x1, line_3,'b--',label="130 dbL: Maximum for Structural Damage Level" )
        plt.plot(x1, line_2,'r--',label="125 dbL: Maximum for Human Comfort Level" )
        plt.plot(x1, line_1,'g--',label="120 dbL: Annoying" )
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
        plt.ylabel('Sound  Pressure Level(dBL)',labelpad=1)
        plt.title('SPL DECAY')
        plt.xscale('log')
        plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")

    def plot_values(self):
        self.test()
        self.frame.destroy()
        frame=Frame(self.graph_frame)
        frame.pack()
        self.frame=frame
        chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure1,self.frame)
        chart.get_tk_widget().pack()

        return None
    pass
main()
```

We have done some trick, we have made new frame as parent frame for `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and if we have to create new `FigureCanvasTkAgg` then we can destroy parent frame and make new `Frame` and `FigureCanvasTkAgg`

Comment: There could be unnecessary `self`. I personally don't use OOP so, you can remove those, if you found any you can inform me, I will remove that from here as well.

Comment: Woooow  thank you! I really appreciate it, its what i was lookin for. This is my first project with tkinter and i tried with OOP, maybe you are right and is much easier without that. But thank you so much.